# Freemarker wrong page view

Tags: java, html, spring, twitter-bootstrap, freemarker

I meet a problem.
I download Bootstrap design for my project. When I unzip design to package and run a page everything is displayed correctly. 
Then I copy html's pages and resources(css, js, images) to my project. Then I refactor index.html to index.ftl and run my project, the index page displayed a wrong view.
I haven't got any errors and warnings in Console and Network(in Chrome).

Freemarker can't displayed page correctly?
MainController.java

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    CategoryService categoryService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "redirect:/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String showIndex(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("categories", categoryService.getAllMainCategories());
        return "index";
    }
}
```

index.html (and .ftl)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Grocery Store | Home</title>
<!-- for-mobile-apps -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- //for-mobile-apps -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!-- font-awesome icons -->
<link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<!-- //font-awesome icons -->
<!-- js -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- //js -->
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- start-smoth-scrolling -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/move-top.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".scroll").click(function(event){  
   event.preventDefault();
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1000);
  });
 });
</script>
<!-- start-smoth-scrolling -->
</head>
 
<body>
<!-- header -->
 <div class="agileits_header">
  <div class="w3l_offers">
   <a href="products.html">Today's special Offers !</a>
  </div>
  <div class="w3l_search">
   <form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Product" value="Search a product..." onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search a product...';}" required="">
    <input type="submit" value=" ">
   </form>
  </div>
  <div class="product_list_header">  
   <form action="#" method="post" class="last">
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="display" value="1" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View your cart" class="button" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
  </div>
  <div class="w3l_header_right">
   <ul>
    <li class="dropdown profile_details_drop">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="caret"></span></a>
     <div class="mega-dropdown-menu">
      <div class="w3ls_vegetables">
       <ul class="dropdown-menu drp-mnu">
        <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li> 
        <li><a href="login.html">Sign Up</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>                  
     </div> 
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="w3l_header_right1">
   <h2><a href="mail.html">Contact Us</a></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"> </div>
 </div>
<!-- script-for sticky-nav -->
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var navoffeset=$(".agileits_header").offset().top;
   $(window).scroll(function(){
   var scrollpos=$(window).scrollTop(); 
   if(scrollpos >=navoffeset){
    $(".agileits_header").addClass("fixed");
   }else{
    $(".agileits_header").removeClass("fixed");
   }
   });
   
 });
 </script>
<!-- //script-for sticky-nav -->
 <div class="logo_products">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="w3ls_logo_products_left">
    <h1><a href="index.html"><span>Grocery</span> Store</a></h1>
   </div>
   <div class="w3ls_logo_products_left1">
    <ul class="special_items">
     <li><a href="events.html">Events</a><i>/</i></li>
     <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a><i>/</i></li>
     <li><a href="products.html">Best Deals</a><i>/</i></li>
     <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="w3ls_logo_products_left1">
    <ul class="phone_email">
     <li><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>(+0123) 234 567</li>
     <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="mailto:store@grocery.com">store@grocery.com</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix"> </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<!-- //header -->
<!-- banner -->
 <div class="banner">
  <div class="w3l_banner_nav_left">
   <nav class="navbar nav_bottom">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
     <div class="navbar-header nav_2">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed navbar-toggle1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-megadropdown-tabs">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      </div> 
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-megadropdown-tabs">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav_1">
      <li><a href="products.html">Branded Foods</a></li>
      <li><a href="household.html">Households</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown active">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Veggies & Fruits<span class="caret"></span></a>    
       <div class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu w3ls_vegetables_menu">
        <div class="w3ls_vegetables">
         <ul> 
          <li><a href="vegetables.html">Vegetables</a></li>
          <li><a href="vegetables.html">Fruits</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div>                  
       </div>    
      </li>
      <li><a href="kitchen.html">Kitchen</a></li>
      <li><a href="short-codes.html">Short Codes</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Beverages<span class="caret"></span></a>
       <div class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu w3ls_vegetables_menu">
        <div class="w3ls_vegetables">
         <ul>
          <li><a href="drinks.html">Soft Drinks</a></li>
          <li><a href="drinks.html">Juices</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div>                  
       </div> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="pet.html">Pet Food</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Frozen Foods<span class="caret"></span></a>
       <div class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu w3ls_vegetables_menu">
        <div class="w3ls_vegetables">
         <ul>
          <li><a href="frozen.html">Frozen Snacks</a></li>
          <li><a href="frozen.html">Frozen Nonveg</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div>                  
       </div> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="bread.html">Bread & Bakery</a></li>
     </ul>
     </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
   </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="w3l_banner_nav_right">
   <section class="slider">
    <div class="flexslider">
     <ul class="slides">
      <li>
       <div class="w3l_banner_nav_right_banner">
        <h3>Make your <span>food</span> with Spicy.</h3>
        <div class="more">
         <a href="products.html" class="button--saqui button--round-l button--text-thick" data-text="Shop now">Shop now</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="w3l_banner_nav_right_banner1">
        <h3>Make your <span>food</span> with Spicy.</h3>
        <div class="more">
         <a href="products.html" class="button--saqui button--round-l button--text-thick" data-text="Shop now">Shop now</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="w3l_banner_nav_right_banner2">
        <h3>upto <i>50%</i> off.</h3>
        <div class="more">
         <a href="products.html" class="button--saqui button--round-l button--text-thick" data-text="Shop now">Shop now</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </section>
   <!-- flexSlider -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" property="" />
    <script defer src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
     animation: "slide",
     start: function(slider){
       $('body').removeClass('loading');
     }
      });
    });
     </script>
   <!-- //flexSlider -->
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
<!-- banner -->
 <div class="banner_bottom">
   <div class="wthree_banner_bottom_left_grid_sub">
   </div>
   <div class="wthree_banner_bottom_left_grid_sub1">
    <div class="col-md-4 wthree_banner_bottom_left">
     <div class="wthree_banner_bottom_left_grid">
      <img src="images/4.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="wthree_banner_bottom_left_grid_pos">
       <h4>Discount Offer <span>25%</span></h4>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 wthree_banner_bottom_left">
     <div class="wthree_banner_bottom_left_grid">
      <img src="images/5.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="wthree_banner_btm_pos">
       <h3>introducing <span>best store</span> for <i>groceries</i></h3>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 wthree_banner_bottom_left">
     <div class="wthree_banner_bottom_left_grid">
      <img src="images/6.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="wthree_banner_btm_pos1">
       <h3>Save <span>Upto</span> $10</h3>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix"> </div>
 </div>
<!-- top-brands -->
 <div class="top-brands">
  <div class="container">
   <h3>Hot Offers</h3>
   <div class="agile_top_brands_grids">
    <div class="col-md-3 top_brand_left">
     <div class="hover14 column">
      <div class="agile_top_brand_left_grid">
       <div class="tag"><img src="images/tag.png" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /></div>
       <div class="agile_top_brand_left_grid1">
        <figure>
         <div class="snipcart-item block" >
          <div class="snipcart-thumb">
           <a href="single.html"><img title=" " alt=" " src="images/1.png" /></a>  
           <p>fortune sunflower oil</p>
           <h4>$7.99 <span>$10.00</span></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="snipcart-details top_brand_home_details">
           <form action="checkout.html" method="post">
            <fieldset>
             <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
             <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
             <input type="hidden" name="business" value=" " />
             <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Fortune Sunflower Oil" />
             <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="7.99" />
             <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount" value="1.00" />
             <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
             <input type="hidden" name="return" value=" " />
             <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value=" " />
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to cart" class="button" />
            </fieldset>
             
           </form>
         
          </div>
         </div>
        </figure>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 top_brand_left">
     <div class="hover14 column">
      <div class="agile_top_brand_left_grid">
       <div class="agile_top_brand_left_grid1">
        <figure>
         <div class="snipcart-item block" >
          <div class="snipcart-thumb">
           <a href="single.html"><img title=" " alt=" " src="images/3.png" /></a>  
           <p>basmati rise (5 Kg)</p>
           <h4>$11.99 <span>$15.00</span></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="snipcart-details top_brand_home_details">
           <form action="#" method="post">
            <fieldset>
             <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
             <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
             <input type="hidden" name="business" value=" " />
             <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="basmati rise" />
             <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="11.99" />
             <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount" value="1.00" />
             <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
             <input type="hidden" name="return" value=" " />
             <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value=" " />
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to cart" class="button" />
            </fieldset>
           </form>
          </div>
         </div>
        </figure>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 top_brand_left">
     <div class="hover14 column">
      <div class="agile_top_brand_left_grid">
       <div class="agile_top_brand_left_grid_pos">
        <img src="images/offer.png" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
       </div>
       <div class="agile_top_brand_left_grid1">
        <figure>
         <div class="snipcart-item block">
          <div class="snipcart-thumb">
           <a href="single.html"><img src="images/2.png" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /></a>
           <p>Pepsi soft drink (2 Ltr)</p>
           <h4>$8.00 <span>$10.00</span></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="snipcart-details top_brand_home_details">
           <form action="#" method="post">
            <fieldset>
             <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
             <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
             <input type="hidden" name="business" value=" " />
             <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Pepsi soft drink" />
             <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="8.00" />
             <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount" value="1.00" />
             <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
             <input type="hidden" name="return" value=" " />
             <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value=" " />
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to cart" class="button" />
            </fieldset>
           </form>
          </div>
         </div>
        </figure>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 top_brand_left">
     <div class="hover14 column">
      <div class="agile_top_brand_left_grid">
       <div class="agile_top_brand_left_grid_pos">
        <img src="images/offer.png" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
       </div>
       <div class="agile_top_brand_left_grid1">
        <figure>
         <div class="snipcart-item block">
          <div class="snipcart-thumb">
           <a href="single.html"><img src="images/4.png" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /></a>
           <p>dogs food (4 Kg)</p>
           <h4>$9.00 <span>$11.00</span></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="snipcart-details top_brand_home_details">
           <form action="#" method="post">
            <fieldset>
             <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
             <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
             <input type="hidden" name="business" value=" " />
             <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="dogs food" />
             <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9.00" />
             <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount" value="1.00" />
             <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
             <input type="hidden" name="return" value=" " />
             <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value=" " />
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to cart" class="button" />
            </fieldset>
           </form>
          </div>
         </div>
        </figure>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<!-- //top-brands -->
<!-- fresh-vegetables -->
 <div class="fresh-vegetables">
  <div class="container">
   <h3>Top Products</h3>
   <div class="w3l_fresh_vegetables_grids">
    <div class="col-md-3 w3l_fresh_vegetables_grid w3l_fresh_vegetables_grid_left">
     <div class="w3l_fresh_vegetables_grid2">
      <ul>
       <li><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="products.html">All Brands</a></li>
       <li><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="vegetables.html">Vegetables</a></li>
       <li><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="vegetables.html">Fruits</a></li>
       <li><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="drinks.html">Juices</a></li>
       <li><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="pet.html">Pet Food</a></li>
       <li><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="bread.html">Bread & Bakery</a></li>
       <li><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="household.html">Cleaning</a></li>
       <li><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="products.html">Spices</a></li>
       <li><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="products.html">Dry Fruits</a></li>
       <li><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="products.html">Dairy Products</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 w3l_fresh_vegetables_grid_right">
     <div class="col-md-4 w3l_fresh_vegetables_grid">
      <div class="w3l_fresh_vegetables_grid1">
       <img src="images/8.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 w3l_fresh_vegetables_grid">
      <div class="w3l_fresh_vegetables_grid1">
       <div class="w3l_fresh_vegetables_grid1_rel">
        <img src="images/7.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
        <div class="w3l_fresh_vegetables_grid1_rel_pos">
         <div class="more m1">
          <a href="products.html" class="button--saqui button--round-l button--text-thick" data-text="Shop now">Shop now</a>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w3l_fresh_vegetables_grid1_bottom">
       <img src="images/10.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
       <div class="w3l_fresh_vegetables_grid1_bottom_pos">
        <h5>Special Offers</h5>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 w3l_fresh_vegetables_grid">
      <div class="w3l_fresh_vegetables_grid1">
       <img src="images/9.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
      </div>
      <div class="w3l_fresh_vegetables_grid1_bottom">
       <img src="images/11.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="clearfix"> </div>
     <div class="agileinfo_move_text">
      <div class="agileinfo_marquee">
       <h4>get <span class="blink_me">25% off</span> on first order and also get gift voucher</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="agileinfo_breaking_news">
       <span> </span>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<!-- //fresh-vegetables -->
<!-- newsletter -->
 <div class="newsletter">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="w3agile_newsletter_left">
    <h3>sign up for our newsletter</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="w3agile_newsletter_right">
    <form action="#" method="post">
     <input type="email" name="Email" value="Email" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}" required="">
     <input type="submit" value="subscribe now">
    </form>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix"> </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<!-- //newsletter -->
<!-- footer -->
 <div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-3 w3_footer_grid">
    <h3>information</h3>
    <ul class="w3_footer_grid_list">
     <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="products.html">Best Deals</a></li>
     <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
     <li><a href="short-codes.html">Short Codes</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 w3_footer_grid">
    <h3>policy info</h3>
    <ul class="w3_footer_grid_list">
     <li><a href="faqs.html">FAQ</a></li>
     <li><a href="privacy.html">privacy policy</a></li>
     <li><a href="privacy.html">terms of use</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 w3_footer_grid">
    <h3>what in stores</h3>
    <ul class="w3_footer_grid_list">
     <li><a href="pet.html">Pet Food</a></li>
     <li><a href="frozen.html">Frozen Snacks</a></li>
     <li><a href="kitchen.html">Kitchen</a></li>
     <li><a href="products.html">Branded Foods</a></li>
     <li><a href="household.html">Households</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 w3_footer_grid">
    <h3>twitter posts</h3>
    <ul class="w3_footer_grid_list1">
     <li><label class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></label><i>01 day ago</i><span>Non numquam <a href="#">http://sd.ds/13jklf#</a>
      eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et
      <a href="#">http://sd.ds/1389kjklf#</a>quo nulla.</span></li>
     <li><label class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></label><i>02 day ago</i><span>Con numquam <a href="#">http://fd.uf/56hfg#</a>
      eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et
      <a href="#">http://fd.uf/56hfg#</a>quo nulla.</span></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix"> </div>
   <div class="agile_footer_grids">
    <div class="col-md-3 w3_footer_grid agile_footer_grids_w3_footer">
     <div class="w3_footer_grid_bottom">
      <h4>100% secure payments</h4>
      <img src="images/card.png" alt=" " class="img-responsive" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 w3_footer_grid agile_footer_grids_w3_footer">
     <div class="w3_footer_grid_bottom">
      <h5>connect with us</h5>
      <ul class="agileits_social_icons">
       <li><a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="google"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="dribbble"><i class="fa fa-dribbble" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
   </div>
   <div class="wthree_footer_copy">
    <p>© 2016 Grocery Store. All rights reserved | Design by <a href="http://w3layouts.com/">W3layouts</a></p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<!-- //footer -->
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hover(            
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideDown("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');        
        },
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideUp("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');       
        }
    );
});
</script>
<!-- here stars scrolling icon -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   /*
    var defaults = {
    containerID: 'toTop', // fading element id
    containerHoverID: 'toTopHover', // fading element hover id
    scrollSpeed: 1200,
    easingType: 'linear' 
    };
   */
        
   $().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });
        
   });
 </script>
<!-- //here ends scrolling icon -->
<script src="js/minicart.js"></script>
<script>
  paypal.minicart.render();

  paypal.minicart.cart.on('checkout', function (evt) {
   var items = this.items(),
    len = items.length,
    total = 0,
    i;

   // Count the number of each item in the cart
   for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    total += items[i].get('quantity');
   }

   if (total < 3) {
    alert('The minimum order quantity is 3. Please add more to your shopping cart before checking out');
    evt.preventDefault();
   }
  });

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Images hosting:

link html page view (correct)
https://ibb.co/frTcaw

ling ftl page view (wrong)
https://ibb.co/fLUpoG

project structure:

```
-web app
 -css
 -js
 -fonts
 -images
 -WEB-INF
    -view
     -ftl
      index.ftl
```

Paths to css, fonts and js in ftl page is true.
How can I make a correct view?

Comment: As you don't have any FreeMarker directives/interpolations there, FreeMarker just sends back the template content to the browser as is. So it's rather strange that it's broken then. I would think there's some kind of oversight there. (You can also just look at the source view in the browser, or save the page. The two HTML-s should be identical.)

Comment: @ddekany You are right! I run the project. Go to /index. Copy code of page. Make in Note a new document with code from copied page. And it was okey. Freemarker break design. 
So i would try to find another design. Thank you!

Comment: So what you are saying is that if you copy the HTML generated by FreeMarker and open it as a local `.html` file then it works? Because that just proves that FreeMarker does not break the design. (It's not running in the browser, it just generates the HTML on the server, and that's all.) Maybe something in the HTTP response headers (aren't set by FreeMarker) makes the difference? Then press F12 in the browser and check them.